# Spring Boot Autowire package structure

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I try to get spring boots @Autowire annotation to work. Unfortunately it doesn't init my objects in some cases. I was wondering if it has something to do with my package structure:

[image: Package Structure]

For example, when I try to do it in my controller classes, it works fine. But when I do it in my subscriber class, it doesn't work.

**Controller**

```
public abstract class Controller<T> {

    @Autowired
    protected Crud<T> crud; // not null
...
```

**Subscriber**

```
public class LocationMessageSubscriber implements Subscriber {

    @Autowired
    public Crud<Sms> crud; //null
...
```

I tried almost all annotiations in my subscriber class, but non of them was working. What can I do?

Info: The @SpringBootApplication annotation is in my App class and this class is located in my main package.

Comment: From your screenshot it looks like the App class is in your rest package. Can you confirm that?

Comment: No its in my main package, I moved it there after taking the screenshot...

Comment: Both is not working

Comment: How do you instantiate `LocationMessageSubscriber`?

Comment: I pass it to the cep framework in my CepInit class. ```public static void init() {
        CepManager cepManager = CepManager.getInstance();

        cepManager.addSubscriber(STATEMENT, new LocationMessageSubscriber());
    }```

Comment: Is it a problem that the methode is static?

Comment: Or is it a problem how I start the framework in general. ```@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
        CepStart.init();
    }
}```